# how to prove Theorem 3.5.4 in 《Types and Programming Languages》using Coq?

Tags: coq, proof

Update: with the help of Arthur Azevedo De Amorim, I finally manage it. The code is attached at the end of the question.

---

I am reading the book 《Types and Programming Languages》, and I am trying to prove each theorem(lemma) in this book using coq. When it came to the theorem 3.5.4, I tried and could not manage it. Here is the problem description.

A small language with AST:

```
t = :: true
    :: false
    :: if t then t else t
```

The evaluation rules are:

```
1. if true then t2 else t3 -> t2 (eval_if_true)
2. if false then t2 else t3 -> t3 (eval_if_false)
3.             t1 -> t1'
         ------------------------  (eval_if)
         if t1 then t2 else t3 -> 
           if t1' then t2 else t3
```

The theorem I want to prove is: for any t1 t2 t3, given t1 -> t2 and t1 -> t3, then t2 = t3.

And I build the type and proposition in Coq as below:

```
Inductive t : Type :=
| zhen (* represent true *)
| jia  (* represent false *)
| if_stat : t -> t -> t -> t.

Inductive eval_small_step : t -> t -> Prop :=
| ev_if_true : forall (t2 t3 : t),
    eval_small_step (if_stat zhen t2 t3) t2
| ev_if_false : forall (t2 t3 : t),
    eval_small_step (if_stat jia t2 t3) t3
| ev_if : forall (t1 t2 t3 t4 : t),
    eval_small_step t1 t2 ->
    eval_small_step (if_stat t1 t3 t4) (if_stat t2 t3 t4).

Theorem determinacy : forall (t1 t2 t3 : t),
    eval_small_step t1 t2 -> eval_small_step t1 t3 -> t2 = t3.
```

And I tried to induction on `eval_small_step t1 t2` as mentioned in the book. But I failed:

```
Proof.
  intros t1 t2 t3.
  intros H1 H2.
  induction H1.
  - inversion H2. reflexivity. inversion H4.
  - inversion H2. reflexivity. inversion H4.
  - assert (H: eval_small_step (if_stat t1 t0 t4) (if_stat t2 t0 t4)).
    {
      apply ev_if. apply H1.
    }
    Abort.
```

Since the inductive hypothesis is not generic.

```
IHeval_small_step : eval_small_step t1 t3 -> t2 = t3
```

Could any one help me with this proof?

---

Proof:

```
Inductive t : Type :=
| zhen (* represent true *)
| jia  (* represent false *)
| if_stat : t -> t -> t -> t.

Inductive eval_small_step : t -> t -> Prop :=
| ev_if_true : forall (t2 t3 : t),
    eval_small_step (if_stat zhen t2 t3) t2
| ev_if_false : forall (t2 t3 : t),
    eval_small_step (if_stat jia t2 t3) t3
| ev_if : forall (t1 t2 t3 t4 : t),
    eval_small_step t1 t2 ->
    eval_small_step (if_stat t1 t3 t4) (if_stat t2 t3 t4).

Theorem determinacy : forall (t1 t2 t3 : t),
    eval_small_step t1 t2 -> eval_small_step t1 t3 -> t2 = t3.

Proof.
  intros t1 t2 t3.
  intros H1.
  revert t3.
  induction H1.
  - intros t0. intros H.
    inversion H.
    + reflexivity.
    + inversion H4.
  - intros t0. intros H.
    inversion H.
    + reflexivity.
    + inversion H4.
  - intros t0.
    intros H.
    assert(H': eval_small_step (if_stat t1 t3 t4) (if_stat t2 t3 t4)).
    {
      apply ev_if. apply H1.
    }
    inversion H.
    + rewrite <- H2 in H1. inversion H1.
    + rewrite <- H2 in H1. inversion H1.
    + assert(H'': t2 = t6).
      {
        apply IHeval_small_step.
        apply H5.
      }
      rewrite H''. reflexivity.
Qed.
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is a typical trap for beginners. The induction hypothesis is not sufficiently general because you introduced `t3` before performing the induction, which has the effect of fixing `t3` "across all induction steps". In your case, you need to introduce `t3` so that you can introduce `H1` and induct on it, so you can simply put `t3` back into the context by using the `revert` or `generalize dependent` tactics.  Simply begin your proof like this:

```
Proof.
  intros t1 t2 t3.
  intros H1.
  revert t3.
  induction H1. (* ... *)
```

This problem is also explained in the [Software Foundations book](https://softwarefoundations.cis.upenn.edu/current/Tactics.html); simply look up "`generalize dependent`" there. (I am sure this question has already showed up on Stack Overflow as well, but couldn't find a reference, if somebody is willing to help.)

Comment: I have tried this but failed.  see here: https://pasteboard.co/huwdXIknB.png

The induction hypothesis is still not sufficiently general.

Comment: The induction hypothesis is fine, I believe, but you probably need to invert H and H1.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I finally manage it. The proof is attached in the question.